# How to set GUID as Value and Name in text in Select using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making a drop-down list in which i need to fill country-list. I am fetching country-list and want to set GUID as value and Country Name as Text in select using angularjs.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Country" ng-model="activeCustomer.associatedCountryID" ng-options="country.countryid as country.name for country in CountryList" required></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own objects in the ng-options. Is this what you meant:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    data-placeholder="Country" 
    ng-model="activeCustomer.associatedCountry" 
    ng-options="{ GUID: country.countryid, Text: country.name } as country.name for country in CountryList" 
    required>
</select>
```